# "Screen Flip" Simple Assembly Program

Tags: assembly, dosbox

So I'm working on my first project in my Machine Organization class. When the program runs, it is supposed to flip the screen vertically. For example, all characters and numbers on the left side will be flipped to the right side and vice versa. To achieve this, `loop25` loops 25 times for each row, moving up a row each loop. Each loop also calls the `flipRow` PROC. This procedure is supposed to take the two outer characters and swap them, move in, and repeat until it reaches the center. Basically it just wont assemble. I know the problem has something to do with the `loopRow` LOOP, but I am not experienced enough yet to know how to fix it.

```
MyData SEGMENT

    row DB 80

MyData ENDS                       

;------------------------------------------------------------------------     CODE SEGMENT
MyCode SEGMENT
        ASSUME CS:MyCode, DS:MyData   

MainProg  PROC                

    MOV     AX, MyData             
    MOV     DS, AX                 
    MOV     AX, 0B800h         
    MOV     ES, AX

    MOV BX, (25 * 160)


    loop25: 

      CALL flipRow

      SUB BX, 160                  
      CMP BX, 0
    JNE loop25                ;if not equal to 0, numLoops - 1 and repeat

    MOV     AH, 4Ch                
    INT     21h                   

MainProg ENDP  

flipRow  PROC 

    MOV AX, 158 

  loopRow:
    MOV DX, ES: [ (BX - 160) + ((AX - 158) * -1) ] 
    MOV CX, ES: [ (BX - 160) + AX ]
    MOV ES: [ (BX - 160) + ((AX - 158) * -1) ], CX
    MOV ES: [ (BX - 160) + AX ], DX
  DEX AX
  DEC AX
  DEC row
  DEC row
  CMP row, 80
  JNE loopRow 

    RET
flipRow ENDP                 

MyCode ENDS                       

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
END MainProg
```

Comment: You should always include the exact error messages in your question. Make sure that you adhere to the addressing mode limitations for 16-bit code [as described here](http://wiki.osdev.org/Real_Mode#Addressing_Modes) (or in Intel's Software Developer's Manual).

Comment: "it is supposed to flip the screen vertically. For example, all characters and numbers on the left side will be flipped to the right side and vice versa" - that describes a _horizontal_ flip (around a central vertical _axis_).

Comment: Calculate the memory offsets you wish to swap in `SI` and `DI`, with *processor* instructions, not *assembler* instructions, at the start of each screen line loop. Then swap `ES:[SI]` with `ES:[DI]`. Then increment / decrement `SI` / `DI` as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
    MOV DX, ES: [ (BX - 160) + ((AX - 158) * -1) ]
```

You seem to seriously overestimate the addressing mode capabilities of the processor :p

In this case, essentially, you need to calculate the address (into a register) *before* trying to load from it. You can't use expressions like '(AX - 158) * -1' in assembly. You need to break it down into individual instructions (subtract 158 from AX, then negate it).

```
  DEX AX
```

There is no 'DEX' instruction.

```
  DEC row
  DEC row
```

Why do you decrement `row` twice?

```
 CMP row, 80
 JNE loopRow
```

Why are you comparing `row` to 80 after decrementing it? (How do you expect it to reach the value 80?) Incidentally, you do not initialize `row` when you are starting a new row. Also, why is it called "row" when it appears to be counting columns?